# Qt - speech bubble widget

Tags: qt

Does anybody know if there is a Qt widget that simulates this effect?

[image: Screenshot of the desired effect]

What I want to do is when the user inputs some data and these data are invalid, this bubble appears and tell to user 'hey, there is an error here!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would use a frameless (setting Qt::FramelessWindowHint) [QDialog](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#details) with a [custom painting](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet.html).

Comment: How do I paint a window like a balloon? Do you have any example?